# Question about proving fundamental theorem of linear algebra when S = S^2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose S is a square matrix of dimensions nxn and it fulfils the condition  $ S=S^2 $, how can we prove that $ Col(S)⊕ Null(S) = R^n $

I'm confused at how to start proving this question, I know I have to use The Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

Comment: Depends on the tools you have. You could note that $S^2-S=0$, so the minimal polynomial divides $X^2-X=X(X-1)$. So the minimal polynomial is either $X,~X-1$, or $X(X-1)$.In the first case, $S=0$, in the second, $S=\operatorname{id}$, and in the third case, $\mathbb R^n=\ker (S)\oplus\ker (S-1)$. Now show that all three lead to $\mathbb R^n=\operatorname{Null}(S)\oplus\operatorname{Col}(S)$.

Comment: What exactly is it that you call “The Fundamental theorem of Linear Algebra”? I know a couple of theorems that might be so dubbed, but I do not know of any one theorem universally known that way (as opposed to “... of Algebra” or “... of Arithmetic”).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that $ ()⊕(^T)=^ $

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos sorry, but what is id? how would you show that they all lead to that?

Comment: $\operatorname{id}$ is the identity map/matrix. In the case $S\in\{0,1\}$ you can simply calculate the null- and column spaces. It will then be easy to show that their direct sum is $\mathbb R^n$. And for the last case, you just need to show that $\ker S=\operatorname{Null}S$ and $\ker S-1=\operatorname{Col}S$.